# Incompatible type from type void*

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to malloc for the struct, customerInformation. But, I keep getting the "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct CustomerInformation’ from type ‘void *’". What am I missing in my declaration? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
struct CustomerInformation *result=malloc(sizeof(struct CustomerInformation)*100000);

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     result[i]=malloc(sizeof(struct CustomerInformation));
 }
```

Comment: that's because `result[i]` store a value, but `malloc` return a pointer `void *`

Comment: You already allocated memory for 100000 `struct CustomerInformation`.  There is no need to then try and allocate each individual one, unless your struct is huge and you need to the main array to store pointers instead of values (in which case the type of `result` is wrong).  What you _should_ do in that loop is _initialize_ each element with actual data.

Answer (score 1):

`result[i]` has `struct CustomerInformation` for type (not a pointer), but you're assigning a `void *` (a pointer).

---

If you want a pointer to an array of structs:

```c
struct CustomerInformation *result = malloc(sizeof(struct CustomerInformation*) * 100000);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    result[i].cust_id = ...;
}
```

One giant block of memory containing 100000 CustomerInformation structs.

---

If you want a pointer to an array of pointers to structs:

```c
struct CustomerInformation **result = malloc(sizeof(struct CustomerInformation*) * 100000);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    result[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct CustomerInformation));

    result[i]->cust_id = ...;
}
```

One giant block of memory containing 100000 pointers, plus `n` smaller ones each containing a CustomerInformation struct.